Trouble with Dead Letter Queue Purging in Spring Boot RabbitMQ Application with Retry Policy
I'm developing a Spring Boot application integrated with RabbitMQ, and I've encountered an issue with the dead letter queue (DLQ). Here's the scenario:

Retry Policy: I've implemented a retry policy(RetryOperationsInterceptor) for messages in queue A. When a message encounters an exception, it remains in the unacked state and is retried according to a policy that increases intervals from 2 seconds up to 5 minutes.

DLQ Problem: After consuming a message from the DLQ, encountering an exception, it remains in the "unacked" status, preventing the queue from being purged. However, after a certain period (like 1 hour), the message transitions to the "ready" status, enabling the queue to be purged completely(but still retrying).


My goal is to ensure that messages in the "unacked" status do not prevent the DLQ from being purged entirely. Additionally, understanding why messages transition to the "ready" status after a delay could provide insights into resolving this issue.
Here's the retry policy implementation:
@Bean
public RetryOperationsInterceptor retryInterceptor() {
    return RetryInterceptorBuilder.stateless()
            .backOffOptions(2 * 1000, 2.0, 5 * 60 * 1000) // Initial interval = 2s Max-Interval = 5min
            .maxAttempts(70) // The message will drop after 70 times failure
            .build();
}

@Bean("factory")
public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory telegramDLQContainerFactory(SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
    SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
    configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
    factory.setAdviceChain(retryInterceptor());
    return factory;
}

Below is the implementation of the listener:
 @RabbitListener(
            id = "dlq-listener",
            concurrency = "1",
            containerFactory = "factory"
    )
    private void onMessage(Message message) {

        try {
                processMessage(message);

        } catch (Exception e) {
                      log.error(e);
            throw e;

        }
    }

Could someone provide insights or guidance on how to address this issue effectively? Any tips, suggestions, or further clarifications needed to assist me in troubleshooting this problem would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance for your help!
